# Android Studio Artic Fox: Cannot resolve constructor 'RotateAnimation(int, int, int, int, float, int, int, float)'

Tags: java, android-studio

he intentado crear un reloj análogo en Android studio, he buscado por cielo y tierra como rotar la imagen del segundero y en todas partes encuentro la siguiente funcion:

```
**RotateAnimation rotar= new RotateAnimation(p1,360,
                    RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0,5f,
                    RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0,5f);
            rotar.setDuration(200);**
```

p1 es la variable donde almaceno el angulo en que debe estar el segundero en el segundo actual, el detalle es que me manda el error: Cannot resolve constructor 'RotateAnimation(int, int, int, int, float, int, int, float)' soy novato en android studio asi que desconozco donde esta el problema, existe un metodo de decirle a android studio que solo quiero que la imagen se incline cierto numero de grados?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error indica que no existe un constructor con los parametros que indicas, si revisas la documentacion de [RotateAnimation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation) el constructor que contiene la cantidad de parametros que usas es este:

```
RotateAnimation(float fromDegrees, float toDegrees, int pivotXType, float pivotXValue, int pivotYType, float pivotYValue)
```

Primeramente, asegura que el valor de p1 es de tipo float y segundo, debes usar `Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF` en lugar de `RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF` :

```
RotateAnimation rotar= new RotateAnimation(p1,360,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0,5f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0,5f);
            rotar.setDuration(200);
```